# Are the words זרוע and צרוע connected?

Tags: passover, commentaries, passover-seder-hagada

Are the words זרוע the bone which is used with Pesach, and צרוע the outstretched arm of our G-d grammatically symbolically connected?

Comment: something wrong with this question. Of course they are connected they both mean arm. Must be a mistake in your spelling.

Comment: Where does it say צרוע means outstretched arm?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hirsch explains in his commentary on Chumash (Vayikra 13:2) that "צרע is inner rot which breaks out externally while נגע strikes externally, זרה is throw away and remove, and זרא means to throw up."

Seemingly, the connected root of these words refer to projecting something externally. Therefore, **זרוע** is an **outstretched arm** while **צרוע** is the **inner rot blossoming externally** on one's skin in the form of tzara'as. (That is the connection between זרוע and צרוע. is [not](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02xpWQuSZof43NGGiTqfifsDTD7XA%3A1586658252329&source=hp&ei=zHuSXu7REJOxytMPldCH0AI&q=%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%20translate&oq=%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%20translate&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6BggAEAoQEzoECAAQEzoICAAQChAeEBM6CggAEAUQChAeEBM6BAgAEAE6BggAEAoQAToICAAQChABECpKIQgXEh00LTE2MGcyMjlnMTIzZzExMmcxNTFnMTQ2ZzEyNEoTCBgSDzQtMWcxZzFnMWcxZzFnNFCaAljcE2DCFGgAcAB4AIABywGIAa4KkgEFMC45LjGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwju54bM6uHoAhWTmHIEHRXoASoQ4dUDCAg&uact=5) translated as an outstretched arm.

If you are asking what the connection is between the shankbone of the Pesach seder plate and the outstretched arm, they are both called זרוע, and you are correct in noting their connection as the shankbone symbolizes Hashem taking us out of Egypt with an outstretched hand. Hence, [Tehillim (136:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.136.12?lang=bi)) says בְּיָ֣ד חֲ֭זָקָה **וּבִזְר֣וֹע**ַ נְטוּיָ֑ה - with an **outstretched hand** (or zeroa/shankbone) He took us out.

Comment: Where is the word זרוע on this list?

Comment: a good answer (+1) for a question that might not really have been asked. I supplemented this a bit in my own answer, bringing zeroa into Rav Hirsch's system.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Matityahu Clark, in expanding on the Hirschian system of phonemic cognates, discusses (see Appendix B) phonemic class E30, which I would summarize as a collection of triliteral roots where the first letter is a sibilant, the second letter is *resh*, and the third letter is a guttural. This is what NJM referred to in his/her answer. Here is a picture of this phonemic class, from my [Biblical Thesaurus website](http://www.mivami.org/dictionary/clark/%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A2):

[image: Clark phonemic class E30]

In this picture, both צרע (erupt) and זרע (cast out) appear. Clark (following Hirsch) discusses a "cognate meaning", that is, the meaning associated with the entire class. The cognate meaning he gives (in the entry for צרע on page 222) is "project outward".

Meanwhile, as mentioned in the comments on your question, the word "outstretched arm" is actually זרוע with a zayin, just like the זרוע which is the bone on the seder plate. The צ does not appear in either word. Yes, these are etymologically related. The part of the animal, the shank (and thus shankbone), is parallel to the arm of a person. See this image of a beef shank:

[image: shank cut of meat]

Metaphorically, God showed might with an "outstretched zeroah / arm".